# C# MVC AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app and can't get this AJAX request to work. When putting breakpoints in code on [HttpPost] the script doesn't even get there.

My JavaScript:

```
function newEmployee() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Personnel/NewEmployee',
            data: {
                Ime: "test1",
                Prezime: "test2"
            },
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success(data)
            {
                console.log("Success!");
            },
            error(data)
            {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public class PersonnelController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Employees()
        {

            //Return View
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewEmployee(string Ime, string Prezime)
        {
            uint UnijelaOsoba = 2;
            Zaposlenik zaposlenik = new Zaposlenik(0);
            zaposlenik.NoviZaposlenik(Ime, Prezime, UnijelaOsoba);
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
    }
```

So far it looks like I'm mistaken on the JavaScript side, as for Chrome Developer Tools Console I get: "POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/Personnel/NewEmployee 500 (Internal Server Error)"

---

SOLUTION (after Shyju's answer):

```
function newEmployee() 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Personnel/NewEmployee',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Ime: "test1",
            Prezime: "test2"
        }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success(data)
        {
            console.log("Uspješno!");
        },
        error(data)
        {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

It was all about stringifying JSON :)

Comment: Check Network tab in Chrome dev tools, see what URL it's requesting, maybe it's not correct, then check @Farhad's answer

Comment: Please put your breakpoint in your action method. 500 error means your POST request is ok , but error happening inside the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

500 Error means, your server code is crashing. You need to put a breakpoint in your action method and find out why

One thing is noticed, which could be the cause of the 500 error is, you are sending the data in an incorrect way. If you are sending a simple lean-flat object, you do not need to specify the content type as application/json. If you do that , you should json stringify your object and send that and make the necessary changes to the server side.

This should work

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("NewEmployee","Personnel")',
    data: {
        Ime: "test1",
        Prezime: "test2"
    },
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: Sir you are a genius! I'll edit the question to show how I solved it with stringifying!

Comment: If it is a lean-flat simple view model, no need to stringify it. It will work when you remove the contentType header option of the ajax call.

Comment: If you are sending multiple properties, create a viewmodel to represent that and use that as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
function newEmployee() 
    {
     var Data = {
            Ime: "test1",
            Prezime: "test2"
        };
         $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: Data,
            dataType: "json",
            url: '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success!");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                    console.log("Error!");
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between success and complete?

Comment: Complete works every time like switch case default . And Success works when you successfully return from controller without error.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now